# init.lua:389: module 'loadcaffe' not found:No LuaRocks module found for loadcaffe

Tags: lua, luarocks

when I do `require"loadcaffe"`I met error as follows:

```
/home/xus/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/xus/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: module 'loadcaffe' not found:No LuaRocks module found for loadcaffe
    no field package.preload['loadcaffe']
    no file '/home/supermicro/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/loadcaffe.lua'
    ......
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /home/xus/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: in function 'require'
    prepro_img.lua:8: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    .../xus/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00405d50
```

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the file for the module loadcaffe? Was it in the paths that Lua searches when it loads a module?

Comment: I have solved this problem by doing luarocks install  --deps- loadcaffe -local，but I met same problem when I require ‘hdf5’.